# npm run sequelize cannot resolve

Tags: node.js, npm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to use sequelize migration:

```
npm install --save sequelize-cli
```

Then I add this in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "sequelize": "sequelize"
  },
```

Then I try:

```
npm run sequelize help:init
```

I got this error:

```
Unable to resolve sequelize package in C:\Projectx
```

The library can be found in the project:

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Got it solve by installing sequelize:

```
npm install --save sequelize
```

Answer (score 0):

If get this error using Windows, Visual Studio Code and the solution npm install --save sequelize does not work. Simply save and close Visual Studio Code, reopen and try again.